# nightwatchjs Error occurred: "There was an error while starting the test runner:"

Tags: node.js, automation, nightwatch.js

I install nightwatchjs globally using the 'npm install -g nightwatch' command. The version is 0.9.16.

Then I simply copy the default google.js (AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nightwatch\examples\tests\google.js) to a separate folder location and executed it

[image]

Any idea why this is happening ?

Answer (score 0):

Could be many things so will start with this:

1) why no --test in nightwatch --test google.js
2) assuming google.js is the test file, does it exist in the Sameera directory or is in examples/tests/?

If 2 is correct I would assume you need something like:

nightwatch --test examples/tests/google.js